# CakePHP - Access $this->request->getData() array in beforeFilter() AppController method

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

'data' array from request is empty when accessed in beforeFilter() method. Is there any way to set and afterwards get the data from the request?

It is a post request. Here's the code:

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    parent::beforeFilter($event);

    $data = $this->request->getData();

    $this->checkService($data['customer']);
}
```

In the beforeFilter method, the debugger says that 'data' is empty.:

[Debugger watches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7z3uW.png)

Comment: did you try `$this->request->getData()` ?

Comment: @SteveKirsch I've tried that. I will put $this in question to avoid confusion.

Comment: This is on a POST request?

Comment: Please put full code in the question so we can get the full idea and help you accordingly.